# How can I run a command after resuming from sleep?

Tags: 18.04, scripts, suspend, fan, fancontrol

I installed a fan control service (fancontrol). It's working perfectly, but there is an issue with suspend: when i wake up my computer, fans going to spin very fast, because fan control service stopped, so I have to run a command:

`sudo service fancontrol restart`

After that, there is no problem. So I would like to run a command (or script) after resuming my computer, which will auto-restart this service.

I wrote an executable script, but it doesn't work...

```
#!/bin/sh

# Resume fancontrol

case $1/$2 in
        post/*)
                service fancontrol restart 
                ;;
esac
```

(Location: /lib/systemd/system-sleep)

What's the problem with my script?

Comment: Did you make it executable (`chmod +x`)?

Comment: Yes, it's executable.